# No overload method for my stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, stored-procedures

I edited my stored procedure to only accept 1 input value. It used to accept 2 but I made my other stored procedure perform the task so now proc_CsStatus() only accepts 1 parameter. However, I get the error:

```
    No overload for method 'proc_CsStatus' takes 1 arguments
```

I thought by removing the parameter and also anything related to the parameter, the problem would be fixed. proc_CsStatus only takes one parameter now.

```
    public static int GetCsStatus()
    {
        using (Entities db = new Entities())
        {
            int Timeout = int.Parse((from stat in db.Messenger_Settings
                                     where stat.SettingName == "CSTimeout"
                                     select stat.SettingValue).SingleOrDefault().Trim());

            System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter s = new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("status", typeof(int));
            int r = db.proc_CsStatus(Timeout,s);
            return (int)s.Value;
        }
    }
```

to:

```
    public static int GetCsStatus()
    {
        using (Entities db = new Entities())
        {
            System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter s = new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("status", typeof(int));
            int r = db.proc_CsStatus(s);
            return (int)s.Value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: After creating the new procedure, did you refresh you edmx?

Comment: After you edited the stored procedure, did you update the code as well?  Technically you're not calling a stored procedure here, you're calling a method on an object in C#.  That method and any calls to it have to be able to compile and run before they can internally call the actual stored procedure on the database.  If you want to add a parameter to that method call, the method definition needs to first be updated to accept that parameter.  It looks like you need to re-generate some data access code after modifying the stored procedure.

Comment: @Habib i did not try to refresh my edmx. I will try that right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refresh your `edmx`. You created the stored procedure, but it hasn't changed in your code base. Update your code (`edmx`) and the error will go away.